# Trying to add Game Center keep getting expected idetifier error

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I am trying to add Game Center to my game however i keep getting the expected identifier or '(' error on the line

```
-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer;{
```

I have spent the whole day trying to google and find a solution but nothing seems to work. I have attached my Viewcontroller.m file

Please help!

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface ViewController ()
    -(void)authenticateLocalPlayer;{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];  
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
        if (viewController != nil) {
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES  
            completion:nil];
        } else{
            if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
                _gameCenterEnabled = YES;
                // Get the default leaderboard identifier.
                [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {
                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    } else {
                        _leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
                    }
                }];
            } else{
                _gameCenterEnabled = NO;
            }
        }   
    };
    }
@end

@implementation ViewController
    - (void)viewDidLoad {  
        [self authenticateLocalPlayer];
        HighScoreNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
        HighScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High Score: %li", (long)HighScoreNumber];
        {}    
        [super viewDidLoad];    
    }
    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];  
    }

    #pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods
    -(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];  
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];  
        [banner setAlpha:1];  
        [UIView commitAnimations];    
    }

    -(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:  (NSError *)error {    
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];    
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];    
        [banner setAlpha:0];    
        [UIView commitAnimations];   
    }

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `;` from that line, make it like so:

```
-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer{
```

Actually, after a closer look at your code, you have a few other issues.

Move the entire `authenticateLocalPlayer` implementation out of your `@interface` block and put it in your `@implementation` block. The `@interface` block is used only for declarations.

So, your code should like like this:

```
@interface ViewController()
   - (void) authenticateLocalPlayer;
@end

@implementation ViewController  
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer{
    // Your code here //
}
```

Comment: i get an error saying Expected ';' after method prototype

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: That has brought up 2 errors which say "Use of undeclared identifier '_gameCenterEnabled'  for both of the following lines,       _gameCenterEnabled = NO;                                                    _gameCenterEnabled = YES;  I apologise if it s a silly question i'm sure you've gathered that i am a beginner thanks

Comment: Unless you declared those variables in your .h file you will need to declare them. I don't see them in your `@interface` block. You need to either put them in your .h file or your `@interface` block.

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thank you very much. All i had to do was declare in interface block with 2 lines                                                        @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *leaderboardIdentifier;
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL gameCenterEnabled;

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Also, you have an empty parenthesis in your `viewDidLoad`. Just as good code practice, you might want to get rid of those.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the ";" between `authenticateLocalPlayer` and " { ".

Comment: i get an error saying Expected ';' after method prototype